# What kind of file copy command is used by msbuild while executing with a '/p:PublishProfile'

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, copy, xcopy

Executing the `msbuild.exe` (VS2013) with the `publishprofile`, ends up coping the artifacts to the nodes. The copy is done using the [COPY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h(v=vs.120).aspx) . Now while publishing the same set of artifacts to another endpoints, i am using [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.11).aspx). Using xcopy to copy the same set of files takes a much longer time (even with parallel thread of copy enabled) compared to the copy done via the copy task. What is the kind of copy used in this version of COPY in msbuild?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you forgot to use xcopy's /d option.

Comment: @HansPassant so with the /d, its going to copy one the files whose source time is newer that the one in the destination folder..... The help shows:  /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
              If no date is given, copies only those files whose

Comment: update: the crystal ball is wrong! time to change it